# Emotion css not rendering after deploy to netlify but works locally

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, emotion, css-in-js

I have deployed a gatsby site on netlify which when viewed doesnt render the css for certain elements, my buttons, but works for other elements like my boxes.

It works and renders fine when i run the site locally.

Rendered locally: [image]

Rendered once deployed: [image]

Im using emotion 10 on a gatsby site.

Im ive tried using both object styles and string styles. The same styling works with other components i have such as a box which uses some of the same css.

This is how the css looks in the dev tools:

[image]

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: are you using [`gatsby-plugin-emotion`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-emotion/)?

Comment: @DerekNguyen yes i am. I have also tried with the jsx pragma tag, still doesn’t work

Comment: mmm, that's weird. Any error during deployment? When you do `gatsby build` in your local, does it still work properly?

Comment: @DerekNguyen no errors during deployment. Im working on a gatsby theme. I have a test site in the same workspace as the theme which runs fine. I also have an nom package of the theme which i installed in another gatsby site and deploy to netlify. Its this one that is not rendering the buttons. It does render other emotion components i have though

Comment: Interesting. Looking closely to the css you posted, it looks like your nested css is not being parsed properly(?) i.e &:hover stuff. Could you post an issue at https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion ? The folks there can probably tell better what went wrong between your local & netlify.

Comment: @DerekNguyen yeah thats my guess, ive tried tweaking it but still no dice. Absolutely, i wanted to check on SO before opening an issue but if you think thats the right way to go then ill drop by there now. Thanks for the tip

Comment: yeah, would love to know their response -- could you drop the link here once you post the issue? good luck!

Comment: sure will do, thanks!

Comment: @DerekNguyen https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1332